# How to deploy an .aar file as a service with 3rd party libs (in WSO2 application server)

Tags: postgresql, wso2, sqlexception

I tired to deploy .aar file as a service in the WSO2 application server. This service need to be dealt with postgress sql driver; so I changed the ant script accordingly to bundle sql driver as well together with the .aar file.

Then I deployed my .aar as a service in the WSO2 application server and deployment was successful. But when trying to trigger this service, I am always getting this error.

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/login`

Tried to trigger the service by coping the same jar into following locations as well, but no luck. {application_server_home}\repository\components\plugins
{application_server_home}\repository\components\lib
{application_server_home}\lib

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy a JAR in WSO2 Server you need to put it in {application_server_home}\repository\components\lib

If it is an OSGi bundle you can put it in
{application_server_home}\repository\components\dropins

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes. {application_server_home}\repository\components\lib is the correct location. While establishing the database connection I didn't specify the driver class correctly; That's why I got that error.

Answer (score 0):

You can put 3rd libraries to resources/lib in aar file. So them will be loading with aar in axis2 service of WSO2.
Also you can put then on server how it's describes in answer of Maninda